# Multiple where for generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need to specify that a generic type for my class implements an interface, and is also a reference type. I tried both the code snippets below but neither work

```
public abstract class MyClass<TMyType> 
   where TMyType : IMyInterface
   where TMyType : class

public abstract class MyClass<TMyType> 
       where TMyType : class, IMyInterface
```

I'm unable to specify multiple where clauses for a type, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latter syntax should be fine (and compiles for me). The first doesn't work because you're trying to provide two constraints on the *same* type parameter, not on different type parameters.

Please give a short but complete example of the latter syntax not working for you. This works for me:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public abstract class MyClass<T>
    where T : class, IFoo
{
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. You're right, the second snippet does work. Sorry - compile error I got was something unrelated to this when I tried. Should have read it properly!!

Answer (score 21):

A question about how to define multiple `where` clauses links here as a duplicate. If that question truly is a duplicate than this "complete" answer must contain both cases.

**Case 1** -- *Single generic has multiple constraints*:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public abstract class MyClass<T>
    where T : class, IFoo
{
}
```

**Case 2** -- *Multiple generics each with their own constraints*:

```
public interface IFoo1 {}
public interface IFoo2 {}

public abstract class MyClass<T1, T2>
    where T1 : class, IFoo1
    where T2 : IFoo2
{
}
```